# displaying my webcam in my webpage is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display my webcam in my web page but the video is not showing and it is fetching this error (Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at )
this is my java script

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
                vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

                navigator.getMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: false    
                }, function(stream){
                        video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
                        video.play();
                }, function(error){

                });
})();

</script>
```

I've read some documents about google removing the createObjectURL but I forgot the source of it, if it is true then what should I do to display my webcam video in my webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use p5js library. For security reasons this doesn't work in stackOverFlow code snippet.

Although you can test it on [p5Js online editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) or test it in your example. dont forget to add the libraries
[this example](https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-capture.html)

```js
var myCanvas;
var w = 640;
var h = 480;
var myVideo;
var frame;

function setup(){

  myCanvas = createCanvas(w,h);
  
  myVideo = createCapture(VIDEO);
  myVideo.id("whatever_id_name");
  myVideo.size(myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height); //480p
}

function draw(){ //loop function

  background(100); //Gray background - not visible
  
 
  rect(100,100,60,30); //Create rect at position (100,100) with size (60,30)
 
  //frameRate(1); //Default frame rate (30 frames per second)
 
  //add the image of the capturedVideo every frame 
  //at position (100,100)
  //with size have of the canvas dimensions - use 0,0 for default video size
  frame = image(myVideo, 160,100,w/2,h/2); 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to play raw data as a [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) stream.

To correct this, change:

```
video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
video.play();
```

To:

```
video.srcObject = stream;
video.play();
```

In addition to this, note that [`navigator.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) is deprecated, and you should really be using [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) instead:

```
navigator.getMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()
```

Comment: I've tried it sir, but it catches an error Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null